# find and mass edit git folders

Tags: bash, find

i try sommething like that

```
me="$(whoami)";

sudo find vendor/Mea/ -maxdepth 1 -type d \( ! -name . \) -exec bash -c "chmod 777 '{}' -R && chown $me:1000 '{}' -R &&  cd '{}' & echo '{}' & echo $(pwd) & git config --global --add safe.directory $(pwd) & git config core.filemode false;   " \;
```

i get

```
user: grek
vendor/Mea/
/mnt/data1/PhpstormProjects/vista_bralion_docker
vendor/Mea/MementoBundle
/mnt/data1/PhpstormProjects/vista_bralion_docker
vendor/Mea/InvoiceBundle
/mnt/data1/PhpstormProjects/vista_bralion_docker
vendor/Mea/AccountancyBundle
```

so $(pwd) - is always in /mnt/data1/PhpstormProjects/vista_bralion_docker
so git command not work , why ?

update 1 :

```
sudo find vendor/Mea/ -maxdepth 1 -type d \( ! -name . \) -exec bash -c "chmod 777 '{}' -R && chown $me:1000 '{}' -R &&  cd '{}' & echo '{}' & echo \$(pwd) & git config --global --add safe.directory \$(pwd) & git config core.filemode false;   " \;
```

same situation like before

Comment: Try to escape `$` in `\$(pwd)`

Comment: same situation  like before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape `$(pwd)` it *and* use `&&` to combine commands.

```
sudo find vendor/Mea/ -maxdepth 1 -type d \( ! -name . \) -exec bash -c "chmod 777 '{}' -R && chown $:1000 '{}' -R && cd '{}' && echo '{}' && echo \$(pwd) && git config --global --add safe.directory \$(pwd) && git config core.filemode false;   " \;
```

This should work. I've tested locally as such:

```
$ find . -maxdepth 1 -exec bash -c "cd '{}' && echo \$(pwd)" \;
/home/bayou/tmp
/home/bayou/tmp/lala
/home/bayou/tmp/framebuffer-vncserver
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this with `-execdir`:

```
sudo find vendor/Mea/ -maxdepth 1 -type d \( ! -name . \) -execdir bash -c "chmod 777 '{}' -R && chown $:1000 '{}' -R && cd '{}' && echo '{}' && echo \$(pwd) && git config --global --add safe.directory \$(pwd) && git config core.filemode false;   " \;
```

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation for `find`:

> -exec utility [argument ...] ;
> True if the program named utility returns a zero value as its exit status.  Optional arguments may be passed to the utility.  The
> expression must be terminated by
> a semicolon (“;”).  If you invoke find from a shell you may need to quote the semicolon if the shell would otherwise treat it as a
> control operator.  If the string
> “{}” appears anywhere in the utility name or the arguments it is replaced by the pathname of the current file.  **Utility will be
> executed from the directory from
> which find was executed.**  Utility and arguments are not subject to the further expansion of shell patterns and constructs.

Note the bolded "utility will be executed from the directory from which find was executed".  If you wish to execute from the lower level directory, use `-execdir`.